# what do lseek and offset do

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

Can someone explain me what does this program do? I can't understand. I created a file named "FILE" and I wrote a five-letter word on it. Now, what does this program do? I don't understand what the offset is... Please explain me, I know it's easy concepts but I can't seem to understand it... Thanks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
 int fd,i;
 fd=open("FILE",O_RDONLY);
 i=lseek(fd,50,SEEK_CUR);
 exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the best place to look for answers to questions like this is the man page.  On most Linux/BSD/etc. systems, you can find them by just typing [`man lseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) (or whatever function you're interested in).

In this case, the man page will explain that `offset` is the number of bytes to seek.  What exactly that means depends on the `whence` argument, but here are what each of them means (copied from the man page):

```
SEEK_SET
    The file offset is set to offset bytes.

SEEK_CUR
    The file offset is set to its current location plus offset bytes.

SEEK_END
    The file offset is set to the size of the file plus offset bytes.
```

So, if you write a five letter word, say "hello", and do `lseek(fd, 2, SEEK_SET)` the cursor will be just before the first 'l', and so if your `read()` the rest of the file, you'll end up with "llo".  Or, if you `write()` to the file, you'll end up overwriting "llo", but the first two bytes will remain the same.

Comment: Is there a way to test it so that I can really see how it works, or is it just an abstract concept?

Comment: The last paragraph tells you how to test it.  Seek to a position that exists, and read.

Comment: @user10567533: you actually need to do something — probably `write()` — after seeking.  There's no point in seeking unless you do something else after seeking.

Answer (score 2):

The program opens a file called FILE in read only mode. Then the code moves the file offset (the current read position) to start 0f file plus 50 bytes. I assume the confusion is around the fact that i now points past the end of the file and the file size hasn't changed ? this is expected behaviour. see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html for more information